# Fazendo width: webkit-min-content responsivo

Tags: css

Eu tenho um fragmento HTML simples:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200">
    <p>Lorem ipsum da dee da herp de derp I like coffee coffee coffee</p>
</div>
```

Meu CSS:

```
div {max-width: webkit-min-content; max-width: -moz-min-content;} 
img {max-width: 100%}
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/vs2zxc8c/1/

Veja como fica no Firefox e encolha a tela da janela. Esse é o comportamento que eu quero: Quando houver espaço disponível, a imagem tem o seu tamanho normal e o texto passará por baixo da imagem. Quando a imagem transbordar, eu quero encolhe-la. Isto funciona no Firefox.

No entanto, a versão webkit parece não funcionar. Aplicando `max-width:100%`  na imagem faz com que a imagem encolha para o tamanho da palavra mais longa do parágrafo.

Existe uma correção para isso em navegadores -webkit, ou isso é um bug?

Answer (score 1):

Podes resolver este problema definindo o tamanho da `div` onde se encontram os outros elementos.

Exemplo:

```
div {max-width: 100%;} 
img {max-width: 100%}
```

Deste jeito, como no exemplo,ele ocupara a tela na sua plenitude (refiro-me a largura) e só assim ela já é responsiva.

Desta forma funcionará em todos os browsers, pois aplicamos uma regra "universal".

Nota:

- Para definir a largura da `div` utilizei `%` para permitir um
  comportamento "responsivo", ou seja, para dar adaptabilidade de
  acordo ao tamanho da tela.

Comment: Você pode fornecer um exemplo completo para que eu entendo?

Comment: Posso sim, mas se fizeres as modificações que sugeri no `fiddle` do teu exemplo poderás observar @NickManning

Comment: Eu fiz, mas o número é maior do que a imagem agora.

Comment: Sim, porque no meu exemplo eu coloquei 100%, tu podes colocar a percentagem necessária, ou teste já com os 200px e funcionara numa boa.

Comment: Eu preciso do número a ser a mesma largura que a imagem, mas eu não sei o tamanho da imagem será.

Comment: Hum, bom, não tinha captado esta ideia na pergunta, desculpa. Só para confirmar, quando dizes "número" te referes ao texto descritivo que fica debaixo da imagem certo?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17711/discussion-between-cold-and-nick-manning).

Comment: número e "<p>Lorem ipsum da dee da herp de derp I like coffee coffee coffee</p>"

Comment: Estou no trabalho, então eu não posso conversar. Talvez mais tarde. obrigado